# Can I view a raw DER binary file?

Tags: x509

so I am learning X.509 certificates and I got a certificate from a random site with openssl, now it is in PEM format, and for example when I open the PEM in a text viewer, I can see it in it's pure PEM view, and I know how to decode it in openssl to see what it actually says.

But when I convert it into a DER format with this

`openssl x509 -in cert.pem -out cert.der -outform DER`

I get a DER file and when I view it in a text editor I don't get the binary view.
Is there a way to see the binary view of DER?

Thank you in advance,
Dubbed_Kiwi

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in CERTIFICATE.der -text -noout
```